# Firebird sequence-backed ID shorthand

Tags: sql, firebird, sequence

What do others do to simplify the creation of simple, serial surrogate keys populated by a `SEQUENCE` (a.k.a. `GENERATOR`) in Firebird >= 2.1?  I finc the process comparatively arduous:

For example, in PostgreSQL, I simply type:

```
pg> CREATE TABLE tbl (
  >   id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  > ...
```

In MySQL, I simply type:

```
my> CREATE TABLE tbl (
  >   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  > ...
```

But in Firebird I type:

```
fb> CREATE TABLE tbl (
  >   id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  > ...

fb> CREATE SEQUENCE tbl_id_seq;

fb> SET TERM !!;
  > CREATE TRIGGER tbl_id_trg FOR tbl
  > ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
  > AS
  > BEGIN
  >   IF ((new.id IS NULL) OR (new.id <= 0)) THEN
  >   BEGIN
  >     new.id = GEN_ID(tbl_id_seq, 1);
  >   END
  > END !!
  > SET TERM ; !!
```

... and I get pretty bored by the time I reach trigger definition.  However, I routinely make `SEQUENCE`-backed ID fields for temporary, development and throw-away tables.  What do others do to simplify this?  Work with an IDE?  Run a pre-processing, in-house perl script over the DDL file?  Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) and you can make it in 4 clicks

I think SEQUENCE is in the SQL Standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create the sequence and no trigger and use the GEN_ID(tbl_id_seq, 1) in your insert query. But as Hugues already said: there are tools (like IBExpert) that will make it very simple for you to generate the boilerplate code.